# pytest: How to show messages from logging.debug in the function under test

Tags: debugging, logging, pytest

```py
''' func.py '''
import logging

def func():
    ''' func '''
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="\t %(filename)s"
        " %(funcName)s"
        "-ln%(lineno)d"
        " %(levelname)s \n%(message)s",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        # stream=sys.stdout,
    )
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.info(" >>> logger func info")
    logger.warning(" >>> logger func warning")
    print(" >>> print func info")


def test_func():
    ''' test func '''
    # caplog.set_level(logging.DEBUG)
    func()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_func()
```

Suppose I save the code above as func.py. When I run

```
pytest -s func.py
```

I obtain

```
" >>> print func info".
```

How can I obtain

```
" >>> logger func info"
```

and

" >>> logger func warning"

when I run

```
pytest -s func.py
```

I wish I can do this for the following reason. I normally insert logging.debug/info etc in the my codes. Sometimes, I want to see messages emitted by  logging.debug/info when I run pytest. I searched the net for quite a while but cant find a way. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So do you want to capture the log records in the test or do you just want to print the messages on test run? The former is achieved by using the `caplog` fixture, the latter by passing the `log_cli` option as described in the [Live Logs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#live-logs) section in the docs.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks a lot. The way to do it: in pytest.ini add: [pytest]
log_cli = true  Then run pytest with pytest --log-cli-level=10 func.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pytest logging ignores options in pytest.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677656/pytest-logging-ignores-options-in-pytest-ini)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To do it by default with every run, add to pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = DEBUG
```

Note: if using a very old pytest, pre-3.5, you will need to set `log_cli = true` in pytest.ini to use the following commands.

Otherwise, for 3.5 and later, you can use just the command line for a case-by-case basis:

```
pytest --log-cli-level=10 func.py
```

Or more clearly:

```
pytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG func.py
```

The command line will always override pytest.ini settings.

Comment: If you're not using a pytest.ini, it's not required; you could also just go with the command-line parameter.

Comment: Here are the log levels: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels
I think it is better to use the names: `pytest --log-cli-level=WARNING func.py`

Comment: You can also provide the 'log_cli_level' in the pytest.ini instead of providing it via the command line. In the pytest.ini be sure to use 'log_cli_level' and not 'log-cli-level'. You can also use 'DEBUG' instead of '10'.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread when I wondered how to expand the "**warning summary**" section on my PyTest run. Playing around with the environment variable `PYTHONWARNINGS` can help with that https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS.
If you do `export PYTHONWARNINGS=error`, you'll see the full stack trace for the warning. However, the run will stop if you are running a test suite.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using only the command line (without creating a pytest.ini):

```
pytest -o log_cli=true --log-cli-level=10 func.py
```