# Logging in view not done when run via pytest

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

When my methods in a `View` class are executed by `pytest`, the logging statements don't produce any outputs on the console. Is that expected behavior or am I missing something?

This is the view:

```py
import logging
from django.views import View
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class FancyWebhook(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("DUMMY logging")
        print("DUMMY printing")
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The logging configuration in `configs/settings/test.py`:

```py
# ...
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler"},
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": os.getenv("DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL", "INFO"),
        },
    },
}
```

The test method:

```py
import pytest
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_fancy_webook_empty_payload_fails(client):
    print("calling client.post()...")
    response = client.post('/pricing/fancywebhook', {}, content_type='application/json')
    assert response.status_code == 403
```

Running the test via `pytest --ds=config.settings.test` only prints the error that `assert 301 == 403` to the console, but neither the "DUMMY logging" nor the "DUMMY printing" statements.

I'm surely missing the obvious, am I not?

Comment: `assert 301 == 403` - the 301 suggests that the response was a 301 redirect. Should the URL in the test be `'/pricing/fancywebhook/'`? If so, Django is redirecting to add the slash.

Comment: You have to specify `-s` for the print output and `--log-level=INFO` for logging output or configure it in pytest.ini.

Comment: See [How to print to console in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617397/how-to-print-to-console-in-pytest) and [Pytest logging ignores options in pytest.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677656/pytest-logging-ignores-options-in-pytest-ini).

Comment: OK, the `-s` and `--log-level=INFO` did help. I added the latter to my `Makefile`. That's much better now. Thanks, @MrBeanBremen.

Comment: Just for the record, @Alasdair is completely right: Adding the `/` at the end of the test URL does prevent the 301 redirect.